# Replacement character issue still not fixed

Tags: c, replace

While

```
GetWindowText(spotify_window_handle, title, title_length)
```

output contain a replacement character.

```
Spotify - Philip Glass � Glassworks Opening
```

I need to replace "�" with "-". I've posted this question some time ago but whit out pasting my code so answer I get assumed that I used wchar_t for title, but I'm not. Title is char*.
Any help would be much appreciated, I'm "new" to C coding, sometime I have big difficulties with some basic/strange behavior like that.

Here is my code:

```
char* spotify_title(int window_handle)
{
    int title_length = GetWindowTextLength(window_handle);
        if(title_length != 0)
        {
            char* title;
            title = (char*)malloc((++title_length) * sizeof *title );
            if(title != NULL)
            {
                GetWindowText(window_handle, title, title_length);
                if(strcmp(title, "Spotify") != 0)
            {
                return title;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Spotify is not playing anything right now. Type !botnext command to restart playback.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("PLUGIN: Unable to allocate memory for title\n");
        }
        free(title);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PLUGIN: Unable to get Spotify window title\n");
    }
}
// End of Spotify get title function
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code your check for "�" -- also, `strcmp()` returns zero if the two strings are identical, so you will probably need something like `if(strncmp(title, "Spotify - ", 10) == 0)` -- also check in the debugger what the "�" actually is (hex)

Comment: What is "", please? You want to replace an "emtpy"-string with a "-"?

Comment: Whta do you mean alk?

Comment: alk maybe your browser is not visualizing char that i need  to replace, for instance this is the char [link](http://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/65533)

Comment: Ohyes, indeed, opening your question in edit-mode allowed me to copy out the invisible (at least for me) character.

Comment: Edward, how to check for "�"? If I write this char in my Visual Studio 2008 got replaced too :((( Also it's a dll so I'm not capable to debug :\

Comment: OT: VS can debug DLLs.

Comment: Write a test program reading out the title, then print out the hex values of the character array elements you read the title into, to exactly identify the titles byte representation. This will enable you to identify the UTF character by its bytes.

Comment: I agree with @alk, you need to know what you are looking for! You can print out the hex characters in the string by something like `char szTmp[256]; int i = 0; while (*title != '\0') { sprintf(&szTmp[i], "%x", *title); i+= 2; title++; }` and display the value of szTmp in a `MessageBox`

Comment: The value I got is ffffff96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your comment above that the character is 0x96 = En Dash character.

```
#define TITLE_PREFIX "Spotify - "
if (strncmp(title, TITLE_PREFIX, strlen(TITLE_PREFIX) == 0)
{    char *pp = strchr(title + strlen(TITLE_PREFIX), 0x96); // 0x96 = En Dash character
     if (pp != NULL)
         *pp = '-';
}
```